# How to run an npm script only once when using docker-compose?

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I'm trying to figure out how to run an npm script using `docker-compose` but I only want to run it once (if the data volume hasn't yet been created -- e.g. the VERY first time I `docker-compose build && docker-compose up`).

The script uses the [Sequelize CLI](https://github.com/sequelize/cli) to run a seed file for the database, but if this is run more than once, it'll error in my database because of a duplicate key constraint violation.

This is because I'm using a data volume (so if it's been run before, it's already persisted).

Oh, and this needs to be run after another script has run (the migration script).

So in order:

1. `npm run db:migrate` <-- this can run every time `docker-compose up` is run
2. `npm run db:seed` <-- this can only run once as long as the persistent volume hasn't been created
3. any other scripts can now run (to start my server)

Are there any concepts like this that can be used with `docker-compose`?

Answer (score 0):

Which database did you use?

In many cases (such as [maraidb](https://hub.docker.com/_/mariadb), [mongodb](https://hub.docker.com/_/mongo)) you can use the directory `/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d`
Every mounted file wil be executed in alphabetic order if the container starts.

To do your operation only on first start the fist part of your script chould be check if there is already a database or not.

EDIT: Take a look to the doku, which file types are supportet. `.sql` ans `.js`  schoul work in the most caes, but for `npm` I'm not shure